# change selection highlight color in eclipse view pane

Tags: eclipse

I recently switched to the Moonrise UI theme, and like it for the most part, except that I find it hard to read highlighted lines in view panels (Package Explorer, Search, Servers, etc).

After looking all over, I haven't found the correct setting to change these. Also, there are 2 colors here - active and inactive. (Examples below)

I could settle for either changing the text color on highlight, or the color of the highlight itself.

Active

[image: active highlight]

Inactive

[image: inactive highlight]

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the CSS file of the them you are currently using.

For example if the theme you are using was GTK and the Color and Font theme was Default. Go to the install directory of Eclipse and go to the themes CSS directory. For example:

plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717/css.

Open the CSS file that corresponds to the theme that Eclipse is currently using. For example, the file e4_default_gtk.css.

Add this CSS style to change the font, font colour and font size. For example, to set to font Arial with color blue and size 8, I would add:

```
    .MPart Tree {
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 8;
    color: blue;
    }
```

Close the file. Close Eclipse and open it back again. You should be able to see the change in Project Explorer, Outline, and other windows that have tree-like UI elements.